# Windows: PeekMessage loop anomaly

Tags: c++, windows

Here's a code snippet from a project I am currently working on:

```
MSG msg;
bool msgAvail = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
while(msgAvail)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    ...
    ...
    msgAvail = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
}
```

While analyzing a customer crash dump, I found that the call to `TranslateMessage()` has the parameter as `NULL`. I am confused as to how could `&msg` become `NULL` in the above scenario. Could someone explain what could be happening in the above code due to which the address of msg is becoming NULL?

Comment: How did you find this exactly? Release build with optimizations turned on might be somewhat confusing while debugging.

Comment: Actually, I should modify my statement - I found this in a customer provided crash dump.

Comment: That is not possible of course, &msg is a pointer to a local variable, it can never be NULL.  If you have confidence that you are diagnosing this correctly (don't, optimized code is hard to debug) then you need to recommend the user to replace his RAM.

Comment: @HansPassant I cannot know the value of `&msg` from the crash dump since it's a pointer to a local variable. I only guessed that it could be NULL by mimicking the code flow using the stack-trace from the dump analysis.

Comment: Well, you guessed wrong.  You didn't give us anything to look at that could help us help you.

Comment: Ok. Here's a question which can help me take this conversation forward - do you know the meaning of the following EXCETION_CODE being shown when using `analyze` in windbg: "One or more arguments are invalid" ?